# yaml templating (maybe yq)

Tags: yaml, yq

Hello currently I try to find a tool (I'm pretty sure yq does not the magic for me) to remove some content from a yaml file. My file looks as following:

```
  paths:
    /entity/{id}:
      get:
        tags: a
        summary: b
      ...
```

So its a typical openapi-specification. I would like to add a magic property for example 'env: prod' so that some endpoints look as following:

```
  paths:
    /entity/{id}:
      get:
        env: prod
        tags: a
        summary: b
      ...
```

Is there a solution to remove all endpoints, which contain env: prod?

I am also free to change the concept. If there would be some transformation with a if else I would be very happy.

Comment: Which yq implementation are you using? The Go version or the Python one

Comment: I am flexible to use both

Comment: The input provided in the question is not valid YAML and hence the YAML parsers yq can't parse it

Comment: Its more an example of the structure.

Comment: YAML templates are not valid YAML (doens't comply with the grammar)

Answer (score 1):

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq):

```bash
yq -y '.[][][] |= ({env: "prod"} + .)'
```

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq '.[][][] |= ({"env": "prod"} + .)'
```

Both produce:

```yaml
paths:
  /entity/{id}:
    get:
      env: prod
      tags: a
      summary: b
```

This adds `env: prod` to every object that is three levels deep. If you want the criteria be more sophisticated, you will have to adapt `.[][][]` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
yq 'del(.. | select(.env == "prod"))' file.yaml
```

Explanation:
You want to delete all the nodes that have a child 'env' property set to 'prod'.

- `..` recursively matches all nodes
- `select(.env == "prod")` select the ones that have a `env` property equal to "prod"
- `del(.. | select(.env == "prod")` delete those nodes :)

Disclaimer: I wrote mikefarah/yq